# Make one very wide div horizontally scroll without affecting the rest of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a table in a page that is laid out like this

[image]

However, with real data (especially on mobile) the chart is going to be significantly wider than the screen size.

Here is my goal. I would like vertical scrolling to work as expected. If more rows are added the page gets longer you scroll... great!

However horizontally I would like it to feel like only the table contents horizontally scroll. So essentially I don't want the header/footer or the search bar or the title or any other HTML content on the page to scroll horizontally. I want it to behave as though a very wide table were not there. However, of course, I would like the table to try to center itself and to scroll horizontally if it needs to.

I have tried `overflow-x: scroll` and that doesn't work as suddenly the whole page is scrolling. The goal is that JUST the table can horizontally scroll.

Comment: add some markup, shows what have you done so far.It is not fiverr/upwork, it is Stack Overflow.

Comment: add overflow-x: auto to only table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div style="width: 100vw; overflow-x: auto;">
    <table>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That except 100vw. For some reason 100% does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the element and also add overflow-x or overflow-y to "scroll" depending on how you want to scroll the element - vertically or horizontally

Answer (score 0):

Set the `width:500px` and add `overflow-x:auto`

Answer (score -1):

Are you using bootstrap? Then try

```
<div class = "overflow-auto"></div>
```

Otherwise for pure css make sure you inlclude a position property:

```
.theDiv{
position: fixed;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```